# Get all Document Libraries on a sharepoint 2013 site RESTfuly

Tags: sharepoint-api

I want to fetch all the 'document libraries' from a sharepoint 2013 site Restfuly.

I tried using

http:///_api/web/folders

but it fetches the list of all possible folders including some internal folders like '_vti_bin' , '_pvt', 'Forms' etc.

I only want to fetch all the user-defined 'Document Library' type folders. What URL should I use?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a direct method to call like getByTitle(). The way I got my libraries list was to call:

```
 http://<site>/_api/web/lists
```

and then take the returned atom-xml and parse it for the BaseTemplate 101 which is Document Libraries.

```
-<content type="application/xml">
  -<m:properties>
          |
          |
     <d:BaseTemplate m:type="Edm.Int32">101</d:BaseTemplate>
          |
          |
```

Hope this helps.
Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292556.aspx)

Comment: ohk. I will try that. Can you please also share the site source where you found this documentation.. thanks

Comment: Sorry I didn't add my source. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292556.aspx I have just used the standard msdn information